# Laravel and angular 2 user access level

Tags: angularjs, laravel, angular, authorization, access-levels

I used laravel 5.3 as the back-end api and anuglar 2 in my project. so every user have some permissions and roles that stored in the database. my question is how we can accomplish that the user can access to the specific route? what should I do in angular 2 to know is user is authorized to access this route or not. my opinion is when the user is logged in to the system laravel pass the permissions to angular but I don't know how to manage that in the angular.

Comment: Are you managing routes through angular or laravel 5.3 ?

Comment: All routes are in the angular